# A behavior I cant understand with css aliginng

Tags: html, css

Sorry for bad english guys...
I searched for some answers for the known question "How do I vertical aligning a block".

I found also some answers. But on the way, I made some weird additional `vertical-align: middle;` and `line-height:500px;`, which centered my block!

Snippet:

```css
.warp-warper {
  line-height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}

.warper {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
}

.inner-block {
  line-height: normal;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: rgb(225, 205, 225);
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="warp-warper">
  <div class="warper">
    <div class="inner-block">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cant understand the reason it works...
I read about `line-height` and `vertical-align` and it seems to be no connection between this two. again - In some weird behavior without one of them, the block wouldn't be centered vertical.

Comment: `vertical-align` is based **directly** off of the `line-height` property. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Perhaps [**this example**](https://codepen.io/edge0703/pen/iHJuA) would help you understand the relationship between `vertical-align` and `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

They [are in the same section of the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) which says:

> 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.

and

> This property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box